# Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::fetchrow()

Tags: php, sql, fatal-error

When trying to run this, it gives me this errror

```
$result1 =& $db->query($query);
    if (PEAR::isError($query)) {
        die($result1->getMessage());
    }

    while($row = $result1 -> fetchrow()){ //this is the line error points to
        $names = $row[1];
        $weekendprice = $row[3];
        $weekdayprice = $row[4];
    }
```

Please note I am required by my professor to use that first line for this specific coursework.